# Rails 3 route helpers in model not respecting sub-URI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nginx, unicorn

Using Rails 3.2.13.

I've got Nginx and Unicorn setup to serve a Rails application from a sub-URI. I have some views where I need to send links to resources, so I'm using a path helper from with a model:

```
def to_exhibit()
  return {
      :label => self.id,
      :name => self.name,
      :edit_path => Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.edit_vehicle_path(self),
  }
end
```

This will produce a URL like `http://localhost:8080/vehicles/10/edit`, but what I really want is `http://localhost:8080/app/vehicles/10/edit` (where /app is my sub-URI). This works fine when calling `edit_vehicle_path` directly from a view. I hacked around this problem previously by creating my own helper:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def self.sub_uri_path(path)
    root = Rails.application.config.relative_url_root
    return '%s%s' % [ root, path ]
  end
end
```

`config.relative_url_root` is defined in my `config/environment` files. This works, but there *has* to be a proper way to do it, plus I don't want to have to maintain this when I inevitably forget about it a year from now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why dont you wrap your routes into a scope?

```
scope Rails.env.production? ? '/app' : '/test' do
  resources :posts, :comments
  ...
end
```

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing

Comment: Thanks, but wouldn't I then have to scope all my resources? What if I want to change the sub-URI at some point? What if the sub-URI is different in testing than in production?

Comment: Only the url would change.. Your link helpers would stay the same. For testing/production differences you can see my updated post

Comment: Yeah, I like that better, but shouldn't there be a way in either the Unicorn or Nginx config to do it that would propagate to Rails?

Comment: I would still like to know if there's a system-level solution to this, but the more I think about it, scoping the whole app from a config is a one-liner, so that's pretty good.

Comment: And this is what I did: `scope (Rails.application.config.respond_to?(:url_root) ? Rails.application.config.url_root: '/') do ...`, where `config.url_root` is optionally defined in my environment files.

Answer (score 0):

You can set it by using the :script_name parameter:

```
Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.edit_vehicle_path(self, :script_name => '/app')
```

http://zergsoft.blogspot.jp/2014/04/using-non-root-mount-point-with-rails-3.html